# Scope or timing issue while loading jQuery and jQueryUI in bookmarklet via <script>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, bookmarklet, timing

**Edit:** Details updated to add differences in Firefox/Chrome behavior

I am trying to create a bookmarklet that will load both jQuery and jQueryUI. The jQuery load uses javascript, but I figured since jQuery was loaded I'd go ahead and use it for the UI loading. ***More than getting it to work I really want to understand why this doesn't work.*** I'm still wrapping my head around scope/closures/etc. But I just don't see why in firefox $ doesn't work but "jQuery" does! The $ works fine in Chrome but I get a DIFFERENT issue there.

**Notes:**
**1)** In FireBug/FireFox I get '$("head") is undefined'
**2)** In Chrome the "$" works fine, but the jQueryUI call fails with Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog'
**3)** the callback guarantees jQuery is loaded by the time I try to use it. In Firefox if I replace "$" with "jQuery" ( such as jQuery("head) ) then the code works!.
**4)** there are no other libraries on the page already using $
**5)** Even more frustrating, in Firefox if I just give in and use "jQuery" rather than "$" and then set the callback from $("#jquilib").load() to call a third function, jQueryUI functions such as .tabs() and .dialog() are unavailalble even though the callback itself was triggered by jQueryUI being available!
**6)** In Chrome the jQueryUI issue goes away if I use setTimeout() to 100ms. If I go down to 1ms or something than the issue persists.

I am using the getScript function from this post: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet.

Below is my code:

```
function getScript(url,success){
    var script=document.createElement('script');
    script.src=url;
    var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        done=false;
    // Attach handlers for all browsers
    script.onload=script.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if ( !done && (!this.readyState
           || this.readyState == 'loaded'
           || this.readyState == 'complete') ) {
        done=true;
        success();
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
        head.removeChild(script);
      }
    };
    head.appendChild(script);
}

function initializejQueryUI(){
    if (typeof jQuery.ui == 'undefined'){
        // jQueryUI library & jQueryUI cupertino theme
        $('head').append("<link href='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>");
        $('head').append("<script id='jquilib' type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>");
    }
    $("#jquilib").load($("<div>jQuery & UI Loaded!</div>").dialog());
}
getScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js', initializejQueryUI); // call initializejQueryUI as callback when jQuery loads
```

Comment: I have no clue what's going on with FireFox. It's becoming clear that in Chrome, though, my call to $("#jquilib").load() is firing instantly ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out after a *lot* of trial an error. I went ahead and continued developing my script in Chrome seems it seemed I got further than in Firefox. When I completed my bookmarklet I tried it on a whim in Firefox and it worked there too! Here's what I learned:

**1)** The `$("#jquilib").load($("<div>jQuery & UI Loaded!</div>").dialog());` call doesn't work because jQuery *removes*  elements added via append from the DOM after processing the script! It was easier just to re-use the `getScript()` function to also get jQueryUI and put the alert in a function called from the callback. The tab creation issue I encountered (item #5 in the question above) was a result of this quirk.
**Reference:** http://api.jquery.com/append/ 
Search for Karl Swedberg saying *"yes, it's normal"*

**2)** Firebug seems to make use of the "$" while in the console, leading a situation like my description above where "$" doesn't work but jQuery() does work. There seem to be some rules governing when it releases the "$" because if i just try running the script again jQuery's $ shortcut suddenly works. This was the most frustrating part because it made it appear like a scope and/or timing issue!